# How do I use the MONTH() function inside an IF/AND function in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to make a sheet where excel grabs the month from a date in a cell as well as the "type" from another cell if those results are true it returns a 1 and if not returns a 0. I also want it to add the rows in the column but that will probably just mean adding SUM() to the front before the IF statement. Here is what I have so far but it won't function.

```
=IF(AND(MONTH($I2) = 11, $K2 = "Yes") $C2 = "Simple",1,0)
```

So here we have if the month in cell I2 is November (11) and the value of the string in K2 is "Yes" and  the value in cell C2 is "Simple" then return 1 other wise return 0.

I have done research online but I am starting to think that this is not possible? Maybe there is a different way through VLOOKUP? Not sure which way to go.

I have found the correct way to do this however it seems that Excel does not want to add the different values it finds when adding ranges to the function such as

```
=SUM(IF(AND(MONTH($I2:$I1000)=11,$K2:$K1000="Yes",$C2:$C1000="Simple"),1,0))
```

Comment: The Formula Seems Incorrect, Hope This is Right Function `=IF(AND(MONTH($I2) = 11, $K2 = "Yes",$C2 = "Simple"),1,0)`

Comment: I am finding that yes, this is correct however I am trying to add the data together in a range of cells and for some reason it breaks whenever I add a range such as K2:K100 and so on. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: can you give some example snaps about what you do. Please post your clarified details along with some sample images on your question by editing. So that will give you the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($I2:$I1000)=11)*($K2:$K1000="Yes")*($C2:$C1000="Simple"))
```

> **SUMPRODUCT** works as **COUNTIFS** in this case which examines the three criteria and return the total count as a result.

Comment: This is it thank you! I have been racking my brain on this forever!

Comment: @mildlylost my pleasure :)

Comment: Great @Terry W.

Comment: @Regiz I believe you can also solve it in the first place if the OP was able to clarify that he or she actually to do the calculation on ranges rather than from single cell :)

Comment: @TerryW Yep !! Tnx

Comment: I am finding that this won't work when changing the type such as "Simple" to "Standard" the number that should be added for Standard is 2 where simple is 1 so that function wouldn't work then. Any suggestions? Also I apologize for the lack of clairty, my brain is fried. I really wish I could just use PHP and SQL but here we are with Excel

Comment: @mildlylost I will need more clarification from you possibly some sample data (or screenshot of a mocked example) to demonstrate the situation where when you changed the type to `Standard` the formula is not returning the desired result, and what would be the expected result?

Comment: @TerryW So there are different plan types Simple, Standard, Deluxe, and Ultimate. Each one has different leves of points. Simple is 0.5, Standard is 1, Deluxe is 1.5, and Ultimate is 1.5. Each month this gets reset so I am trying to grab the month from the date that is entered so I can have a chart that shows the total points aquired from the different plans each month.Also there is an additional range of cells that needs to be set to yes.

Comment: There is data validation for selecting the types of plans and whether another value is yes or not. I can send screenshots, would I add them to the question?

Comment: @mildlylost based on what you said, the formula for `Simple` type would be `=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($I2:$I1000)=11)*($K2:$K1000="Yes")*($C2:$C1000="Simple")*0.5)`, and the one for `Standard` would be `=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($I2:$I1000)=11)*($K2:$K1000="Yes")*($C2:$C1000="Simple")*1)` or simply as the one I suggested without multiplying `1`. A smarter way would be replace the number with a **VLOOKUP** to look up the value by the type.

Comment: Oh ok so you can add an additional number onto that SUMPRODUCT. That might actually do it since once I get the data structred into the month organization Ill just grab totals from there. Thank you once again. you both have been a great help!

Answer (score 1):

The function which u mentioned in your question seems incorrect.

you have closed the ")" before the third condition. Hence the formula won't worked.

your formula (Error Formatted in Bold)

IF(AND(MONTH($I2) = 11, **$K2 = "Yes") $C2 = "Simple"**,1,0)

The Exact Formula which will be worked out. Try This one.

`=IF(AND(MONTH($I2) = 11, $K2 = "Yes",$C2 = "Simple"),1,0)`

Comment: it seems that Excel does not want to add the different values it finds when adding ranges to the function such as  =SUM(IF(AND(MONTH($I2:$I1000)=11,$K2:$K1000="Yes",$C2:$C1000="Simple"),1,0))

Comment: Does this formula for one cell or which is used for multiple cells  individually?